# Multiple definition of operator<< in Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading

When compiling my project I am getting a `multiple definition of operator<<` error from the compiler.

```
inline QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, ValueCountPair const &pair)
{
    out << pair.value() << pair.count();
    return out;
}
```

I have checked and this specific operator is only declared and/or defined once in my entire code base. Why does it say that I have multiple definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this:

- Clean your project by clicking Build -> Clean Project "YourProject"
- Rebuild

I had this same issue, and I assume that `moc` somehow retained multiple copies of my code somewhere, causing the error. When you clean your project and rebuild it removes all the metacode created by the `qmake` and `moc` process, thus clearing the error.

This is a bug on the part of Qt.

Comment: I have had this happen multiple times using Qt Creator. It nearly always occurs because of inline class functions that are defined in the header change in a fundamental way, and other files dependent on it don't get marked as needing to be recompiled. Thus multiple definitions of the same function end up in your project.